# Prove that the angle represents a constant value...

Tags: geometry

Two circles intersect in points B and A. Through the point A is drawn a line that intersects the circles in points C and D. Prove that the measure of angle CBD is a constant value for any line that is drawn through the point A.

Thanks a lot for your possible help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

$$\angle ADB\;,\;\;\angle ACB\;\;\text{are constant (why? Try the constant cord...)}$$

Comment: I think that ADB and ACB are constant because we see that these angles are always subtended by the same arcs. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly @JohnG.: on both circles, we have the arc $\;\widehat{AB}\;$  which both angles above subtend (of course, the arcs are different in the different circles)

Comment: Antonio thank you very much!